# Flutter Database open issue only on remote server

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, google-chrome

I have a strange issue here, I'm trying to use the sqflite_common_ffi_web package for flutter, there is something going on around with database opening, but it only happens if the build is requested from a remotely hosted server. Everything is fine even if a release build is created with chrome run options.

Here is the output:
/shw2 error caught TypeError: WebAssembly: Response has unsupported MIME type 'application/octet-stream' expected 'application/wasm' sqflite_sw.js:4634:78
########### EXCEPTION!!! main.dart.js:49582:17
unsupported result null (null)

What might be the issue?

Tried running in on localhost, the issue is the same, creating a test build with flutter run -d chrome or flutter run -d chrome --release is successful without any database issue.

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/tree/master/packages_web/sqflite_common_ffi_web) and have the `sqlite3.wasm` and `sqflite_sw.js` deployed to the proper directory of the web server?

Comment: Yes, as I have said it works on run mode but not on build mode, both sqlite3.wasm and sqflite_sw.js is there

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved,

Once a build is created with flutter run -d chrome, it actually doesn't load a service worker, creating a a normal build will at the end load a service worker (flutter's own worker) which is somehow conflicting with sw.dart.js

The solution is the following:

```
var swOptions = SqfliteFfiWebOptions( sharedWorkerUri: Uri.parse('sw.dart.js'), forceAsBasicWorker: _useBasicWebWorker);

var _webContextRegisterAndReady = sqfliteFfiWebStartSharedWorker(swOptions);
sqfliteFfiWebLoadSqlite3Wasm(swOptions);
databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfiWebNoWebWorker;
```